# How does the remove in Binary Search Tree work here?

Tags: javascript, performance, recursion, binary-search-tree

I have got a question to the recursive BST Remove Method as a homework.
I know it inserts and lookup values into a binary tree but I don't know how to explain how to delete one.
Can someone please explain me how the method works and also the 2 Questions commented out?
Thank you very much!

```
remove(value) {
    this.root = this.removeNode(this.root, value);
  }

  removeNode(current, value) {
    // Return if undefined or null
    if (value == null || value == undefined) {
      return;
    }
    // If MATCH
    if (value == current.value) {  // ** Question 1:  How does the return statement work here? I mean we overwrite the this.root with the return statement which at Case 1 is current.right. How comes that the output is still the full tree?**
      // Case 1: No Children
      if (current.left == null && current.right == null) {
          return null;
      // Case 2: No Left Child
      } else if (current.left == null) {
        return current.right;
      }
      // Case 3: No Right Child
      else if (current.right == null) {
        return current.left;
      }
      // Case 4: Two Children
      else { // ** Question 2: What do we do here? We find the smallest Node in the rightleft side and then set it to the current.value? What do we replace at current.right? **
          var tempNode = this.kthSmallestNode(current.right);
          current.value = tempNode.value;          
          current.right = this.removeNode(current.right, tempNode.value);
          return current;
      }
      // Loop Left
    } else if (value < current.value) {
      current.left = this.removeNode(current.left, value);
      return current;
      // Loop Right
    } else {
      current.right = this.removeNode(current.right, value);
      return current;
    }
  }

  kthSmallestNode(node) {
    // Loop until node == null and find the lowest value in Node
    while (node.left != null) {
      node = node.left;
    }
    return node;
  }
```

Comment: The return statement passes the node back to the callee, which is the removeNode call on the upper node. That then sets `current.left =` ... I strongly recommend drawing a tree on a sheet of paper and going through all these steps "by hand"

Comment: Danke, hat mir sehr geholfen!